# how to split a string from specific char to specific char

Tags: python, string, split

I want to split a string from "#" to "::" and I want to do this several times, this string about albums and songs and I want to split the title of all the songs and the albums:

```
Input:'the songs is # Moving On:: by Marshmello '#the string
Output:'Moving On'#songs name
```

And I don't want to do that with indexes because the title has different
Length and also the songs with different places.

Comment: Look at `str.find()`.

Comment: Have you considered a regex capture  between the `#` and `::`?

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way I can think to do this is:

```
x = 'the songs is # Moving On:: by Marshmello '
print( x[x.find('# ')+2: x.find('::')] )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to achieve a very minimal solution...

```
re.search(r'#\s*(.+)\s*::', 'the songs is # Moving On:: by Marshmello ').group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str = 'the songs is # Moving On:: by Marshmello'


def find_between( s, first, last ):
   try:
      start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
      end = s.index( last, start )
    return s[start:end]
except ValueError:
    return ""

print find_between(str, "#", "::");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split # first, for all. After that I would split :: in two differents arrays

```
>>> string = 'the songs is # Moving On:: by Marshmello '
>>> string.split('#',1)[1].split('::',1)[0]
' Moving On'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, so you can do exactly that then. You can split the string multiple times as below.

```
"the songs is # Moving On:: by Marshmello".split("#")[1].split("::")[0]
```

This will give you the song title.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice a string like any other list:

```
"Some String"[1:2]
```

would give you

```
"om"
```

And you can get the first index of a particular character like this:

```
"Some String".index("S")
```

would return 0.

For your case, you could do something like:

```
sentence = 'the songs is # Moving On:: by Marshmello '
start_string = "# "
first = sentence.index(start_string) + len(start_string # Add the length of the start string because we want to start the slice at the end of the string 
end_string = "::"
last = sentence.index(end_string)
slice = sentence[first:last]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import re
song = 'the songs is # Moving On:: by Marshmello'
title = re.findall(r'#(.*?)::', song)
print title[0]
```